# Check duplicate values and compare array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array which contains details about "yahoo" and "google".

```
$initial= Array ( [0] => Array ( [user] => Yahoo [total] => 1 [day] => Monday) 
    [1] => Array ( [user] => Google [total] => 2 [day] => Monday)
    [2] => Array ( [user] => Google [total] => 1 [day] => Tuesday ) 
    [3] => Array ( [user] => Google [total] => 3 [day] => Monday ) )
```

I want to check array such that the conditions are:

```
1. from each array take 'day' and comapre with all arrays for particular day
2. if  'day' is same then compare user
3. if "users" are same for particular day then "count total" i.e.,5 for "Google" on monday
4. if "users' are different for particular day then keep "total" as it is.
```

Final resultant array should look like this.

```
$result=Array([0]=>Array([day]=>Monday [user]=>[Google,Yahoo] [total]=>[5,1])
    [1]=>Array([day]=>Tuesday [user]=>[Google] [total]=>[1]))
```

I have tried this for comparing but i am not able to obtain desired output.

```
 $result= [];
 foreach($initial as $key => $value)
 {
    if(!in_array($value['day'], $match))
    {
      $result[] = $value['day'];
      continue;
    }

 }
```

Is there any possible ways to solve this?

Comment: will following answer format work (day is the key of result array) Array
(
    [Monday] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [0] => google
                    [1] => yahoo
                )

            [total] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

)

Comment: yes. i can make modify if i am able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make days the key of your result array then you can use the following loop:

```
foreach($initial as $key => $value)
 {
     $day=$initial[$key]["day"];

     $result[$day]["user"][]=$initial[$key]["user"];
     $result[$day]["total"][]=$initial[$key]["total"];   
 }
```

Comment: it will give undefined index "day"

Comment: i dont want to repeat yahoo and google more than once in an array. i dont need duplicate values of users in array